# How to use if statements in bash scripting

Tags: bash, if-statement, scripting

I am trying to filter lines in a file using a `for` loop followed by an `if` statement with the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

> oldFiles.txt

files=$(grep ' jane ' ~/data/list.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 3)
for file in $files; do
  file="~${file}";
  if [ -e "$file" ]; then
    echo $file;
  fi
done
```

Where `list.txt` is a list of names like this:

```
001 jane /data/jane_profile_07272018.doc
002 kwood /data/kwood_profile_04022017.doc
003 pchow /data/pchow_profile_05152019.doc
004 janez /data/janez_profile_11042019.doc
005 jane /data/jane_pic_07282018.jpg
006 kwood /data/kwood_pic_04032017.jpg
007 pchow /data/pchow_pic_05162019.jpg
008 jane /data/jane_contact_07292018.csv
009 kwood /data/kwood_contact_04042017.csv
010 pchow /data/pchow_contact_05172019.csv
```

I need to append the result in the file `oldFiles.txt` but i'm echo-ing it for now, yet it doesn't show anything on screen.
Everything looks perfect, for example when i replace `"$file"` in the `if` statement with an actual value of a file that `exists` (like this one `/data/jane_profile_07272018.doc`) then it works. Here's a list of files that exists in the file system:

```
jane_contact_07292018.csv  
janez_profile_11042019.doc  
kwood_profile_04022017.doc  
pchow_pic_05162019.jpg
jane_profile_07272018.doc  
kwood_pic_04032017.jpg      
list.txt                    
test.txt
```

My script should `echo` only files that exist in the filesystem, hence the `if` statement.

What is there missing !?

Comment: why are you reassigning`file="~${file}";`?

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano to make it a full path so that it can recognize the file exists in the filesystem. I did this after having tried using the variable directly without reassigning.

Comment: The file contains absolute paths like `/data/jane_profile_07272018.doc`, you don't have to add anything

Comment: Look at https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 for use of `for`, `while`, and commands.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there!!!
I would change a little bit your code to

```
#!/bin/bash    
OLDFILES="odlfiles.txt"    
FILES=$(egrep " jane " /data/list.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 3 ) 
#Alternative using awk with space as default delimiter to get the 3rd column ;)
#FILES=$(egrep " jane " /data/list.txt | awk '{print $3}' ) 

for file in $FILES; do
        if [ -f $file ]; then
                echo -e "[EXISTS]\tAppending to ${OLDFILES} path file: ${file}"
                #Appending now to target file
                echo $file >> $OLDFILES
        fi
done
```

I think you are aware of the use of grep in order of filtering the content of the list.txt. I would recommend you to use in such cases egrep and then the pattern/regex which suits your needs the most.
In this case:

```
    #!/bin/bash    
    OLDFILES="odlfiles.txt"
    WORD2MATCH="jane"
        
    FILES=$(egrep "\s${WORD2MATCH}\s" list.txt | awk '{print $3}')
    
    for file in $FILES; do
            if [ -f $file ]; then
                    echo -e "[EXISTS]\tAppending to ${OLDFILES} path file: ${file}"
                    echo $file >> $OLDFILES
            fi
    done
```

Or maybe in the compact form :)

```
#!/bin/bash
OLDFILES="odlfiles.txt"
WORD2MATCH="jane"
FILES=$(egrep "\s${WORD2MATCH}\s" list.txt | awk '{print $3}')

for file in $FILES; do
        [ -f $file ] && echo $file >> $OLDFILES && echo -e "[APPENDED]\t${file}"
done
```